# Tricky English teacher question on using a verb as a noun

Tags: verbs, nouns

My English teacher today gave us this question:

> Make a sentence using any verb word as a noun.  You can use it as a
>   subject.

But how is this possible?

I thought all the verbs are used for actions, and noun is for something or someone.

So I am stuck on how to make this possible.

Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: Many verbs can also be nouns (called 'gerundial nouns'). One example is _Even occasional social smoking in the office is prohibited_. "Smoking" is clearly a noun here since it is modified by the adjectives "occasional" and "social".

Comment: To infinitives also can function as the subject of a sentence.

Comment: @LucianSava Yes, but not as nouns, which is what the OP asked about.

Comment: You've already done it yourself in the question text! *Please **help*** is a verb usage, but you could have said *I need **help**,* in which case it's a noun.

Comment: @BillJ Can infinitives act as the subject of non-linking verbs? I know that infinitive clauses can; but the only verb form that I can imagine can act as the subject of non-linking verbs is the gerund form.

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed Only infinitival clauses, not just the infinitive verbs alone, can be subjects.

Comment: @BillJ Is that true for the subject of linking verbs too? And does an infinitive modified by an adverb count as a clause, or is just a verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy actually.

What you can do is simply use the verb word itself as a noun (notice how I just used verb as an adjective?).

For example, the word run is a verb.  But the word itself can be used as a noun.

> Run means to sprint with your legs.

Get it?  Any word, even adjectives, conjunctions, adverbs, etc. when you are simply using it as a word can be interpreted as a noun or the subject of a sentence.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In your first example "verb" is not an adjective but a noun modifying the noun "word" to give the nominal "verb word". It is not possible for adjectives, conjunctions and adverbs to function as nouns.

Comment: @BillJ So what's *happy* in "The first 'happy' in your sentence describes the man."?

Comment: The rich get richer and the poor get poorer . . . but it's true that English is more reluctant than Latin, German or French to recategorize *nomina adjectiva* as *nomina substantiva*.

Comment: @StoneyB I give up! Life's too short.

Comment: What is it when we throw someone's words back in their face, quoting a specific word:  "I don't want to hear about 'sorry' ".  In other words, "Don't use *the word* 'sorry' with me. I'm not in a forgiving mood."

Answer (score 6):

I can think of two possible concepts your teacher might be trying to hammer home.

First, as BillJ said in an initial comment, *gerunds* are verbs that function as nouns. Typically, an -*ing* is added to the infinitive verb to form the gerund.

Let's take a few random verbs – *teach, jog,* and *eat* – and try it:

- **Teaching** is a noble profession.
- **Jogging** is good for your health.
- **Eating** too many sweets might cause you to gain weight.

On the other hand, maybe your teacher wasn't thinking about gerunds at all. It might be surprising for a learner to realize how many English words have definitions as **[both nouns *and* verbs](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning%20of%20word)**.

For example, consider: *pin, list, drink, hold, phone, rhyme, duck,* and *cup*. (In fact, it might be harder to think of a verb that *doesn't* also function as a noun than to think of one that does!)

I will use each of those words in a sentence now, first as a verb, and then as a noun:

- **Pin** the fabric together before sewing. Use four **pins** for each piece.
- **List** all the places we might go on vacation. After that, put your **list** in an envelope.
- **Drink** four glasses of water every day in the summer. A cold **drink** would be nice right now.
- **Hold** your partner's hand gently while you dance. The wrestler put his opponent in a **hold**.
- **Phone** your brother before you leave. Could you please answer the **phone**?
- The word 'phone' **rhymes** with 'loan'. The poet had trouble writing his last **rhyme**.

For these last two, I'll use both the verb and noun in the same sentence:

- You should **duck** if you hear the hunters shooting at a **duck**.
- This piece is very delicate, so please carefully **cup** your hands around the **cup**.

---

As an interesting footnote, other words in this answer that can be used as both a noun and verb include: *hammer, jog, home, function, sentence, form, take, hand, vacation, envelope, water, dance, answer,* and *can*. (This is not the complete list.)