# Can an infinitive form of a verb act as a subject?

Tags: subjects

I saw in a book a sentence as:

> To move such a large mass requires a large amount of force. The intersect between the two displacements makes an angle of ninety degrees.

What is acting as a subject in the first sentence?
Also, I believe **intersection** should be placed there instead of **intersect** in the second sentence.

Comment: Do you mean "intersect"?

Comment: Just as in the first sentence, _of course_ an infinitive can act as a subject in English! _"To err is human."_ ... _"To be or not to be, that is the question."_ Do those quotations ring a bell? Before posing the question, did you do any research on your own? Also, please tell us what English dictionaries you consulted to learn about the English noun _intersect._

Comment: Yes, of course. In your example the infinitival clause _To move such a large mass_ is subject. Here are two more: _To turn back now would be a mistake_; _For you to accept responsibility would be the fairest thing to do_.

Answer (score 4):

Infinitives (to+V) and gerunds (V-ing) can act as nouns and therefore can be used as subjects or objects in sentences.

Both can be used as **subjects**. **Using** the gerund is more usual. **To use** the infinitive is very formal and is more often found in formal writing than in spoken everyday language.

Both can be used as **objects** but the choice in that case does not depend on register but on what verb they depend on. Dictionaries and/or grammar books usually tell what to use with what verbs. For example:

- I enjoy swimming.
- I want to swim across the river.
- I like running.
- I like to run.

[Here is an extensive lesson](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/part_1.htm) on how to use infinitives and gerunds as subjects and objects.

Comment: What justifies the downvote?

Comment: +1 But I think extraposed infinitive is even more common. "It requires a large amount of force to move such a large mass."

Comment: Laure, there's an upvoted comment [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/132383/tricky-english-teacher-question-on-using-a-verb-as-a-noun) that says that to infinitive can never be a noun. However, [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm) it says that *Both gerunds and infinitives can be nouns*. So, I personally don't know whom to believe.

Comment: @LucianSava I think what BillJ meant to say was that the -ing form can used as a noun and it's technically referred to as a gerundial noun. This gerundial noun functions fully as a noun; that is, it takes a determiner and can be infected for plural(-s) form. But infinitives are always verbs, even though they can be used to realize a subject position.

Comment: Yeah, it might be so.

Comment: @LucianSava I wrote infinitives  can **act** as nouns, which is different from **be** which is the word you use in your sentence. *Be* refers to the nature of the word, *act* refers to the function, the role, of the word, it means they can  be **used as** nouns. I gave an outside reference in my answer, but lots more can be found. [Here](http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-220-Noun-Infinitives.htm), and [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm). And [here](http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-220-Noun-Infinitives.htm)

Comment: Yeah, my comment says *function*, whereas the website that I linked says *be*. BTW, not the downvoter.